# Deriving $-dU/dr$

Tags: forces, work, potential-energy, calculus

If $\vec F$ is a conservative force and $W$ is the work done on an object by that force, than the following are true:
$$\Delta U=-W$$
$$\int dU=-\int\vec F\cdot d\vec r$$
$$\int dU=\int -\vec F\cdot d\vec r$$
$$dU=-\vec F\cdot d\vec r$$
But then our professor immediately skipped to $$F_x=-\frac{dU}{dx},$$ and I really don't see how he got there.

Could someone continue deriving a more general form of his equation from the fourth line of work shown above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from your forth line:

$dU = -\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = -F_x dx -F_y dy -F_z dz$

On the other hand, we expand $dU$ as

$dU = \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial U}{\partial z} dz$,

which implies

$F_x = -\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}$

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into a mathematical concept called a "directional derivative". For a small displacement along a curve with direction and magnitude $\operatorname{d} \mathbf{r}$, the change in a function $U$ along that curve is given by: $$\operatorname{d} U  = (\nabla U) \cdot \operatorname{d} \mathbf{r}.$$ So, when you say that $$\operatorname{d}U = -\mathbf{F}\cdot \operatorname{d}\mathbf{r}$$ for every infinitesimal displacement $\operatorname{d}\mathbf{r}$, especially for displacements in the basis directions, then $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla U$.